# Prove/show that $\epsilon_{ijk}(\hat a_j \hat b_k-\hat b_k \hat a_j)=2\epsilon_{ijk}\hat a_j\hat b_k$

Tags: solution-verification, proof-explanation, tensors, quantum-mechanics

I am simply trying to understand where the factor of $2$ comes from in the RHS of $$\epsilon_{ijk} \left[\hat a_j, \hat b_k \right]=\epsilon_{ijk}\left(\hat a_j \hat b_k-\hat b_k \hat a_j\right)=\epsilon_{ijk}\left(2\hat a_j\hat b_k\right)\tag{a}$$

Here, $\left[\hat a_j, \hat b_k \right]$ is the commutator of operators $\hat a_j,$ and $\hat b_k$ and the Einstein summation convention is being used. Here the operators must *not* be assumed to commute or anticommute.

I once asked my lecturer about why eqn. $(\mathrm{a})$ is true and the usual story is that the "Levi-Civita is anti-symmetric under exchange of $j$ and $k$, so the two terms are the same up to a minus sign which gives the extra factor of $2$". But I'm finding it hard to understand this statement.

So in trying to convince myself that $(\mathrm{a})$ is true, starting with the LHS of $(\mathrm{a})$, I write it out for $i$th component by summing over $j$ and $k$ which run from $1$ to $2$:

$$\epsilon_{ijk} \left[\hat a_j, \hat b_k \right]=\epsilon_{ijk}\left(\hat a_j \hat b_k-\hat b_k \hat a_j\right)\tag{1}$$
$$=\epsilon_{i12}\left(\hat a_1 \hat b_2-\hat b_2 \hat a_1\right)+\epsilon_{i21}\left(\hat a_2 \hat b_1-\hat b_1 \hat a_2\right)$$
$$=\epsilon_{i12}\left(\hat a_1 \hat b_2-\hat b_2 \hat a_1\right)-\epsilon_{i12}\left(\hat a_2 \hat b_1-\hat b_1 \hat a_2\right)$$
$$=\epsilon_{i12}\left((\hat a_1 \hat b_2-\hat a_2 \hat b_1)-(\hat b_2\hat a_1-\hat b_1 \hat a_2)\right)$$
$$\stackrel{\color{red}{?}}{=}\epsilon_{ijk}\left(\hat a_j \hat b_k-\hat b_k \hat a_j\right)\tag{2}$$
In going from the second to the third equality I used the fact that $\epsilon_{i21}=-\epsilon_{i12}$ due to the fact that the Levi-Civita is totally antisymmetric under interchange of $2$ indices. But the final expression, $(2)$, doesn't show where the factor of $2$ comes from in $(a)$. All the final expression in $(2)$ shows is that the starting equation, $(1)$ is true (assuming my reasoning is correct). However, I'm unsure about the final equality and indicated this with a question mark.

So instead, starting from the RHS of $(\mathrm{a})$
$$\epsilon_{ijk}\left(2\hat a_j\hat b_k\right)=2\left(\epsilon_{i12}\hat a_1\hat b_2+\epsilon_{i21}\hat a_2 \hat b_1 \right)\tag{3}$$
$$=2\left(\epsilon_{i12}\hat a_1\hat b_2-\epsilon_{i12}\hat a_2 \hat b_1 \right)=2\epsilon_{i12}\left(\hat a_1\hat b_2-\hat a_2 \hat b_1 \right)$$
$$=2\epsilon_{i12}\left(\hat a_1\hat b_2-\hat a_2 \hat b_1 \right)=2\epsilon_{ijk}\hat a_j\hat b_k \tag{4}$$

But once again, in eqn. $(4)$ I've proven absolutely nothing, assuming my manipulations are correct I have simply proven that the starting equation, $(3)$ is true.

So to summarize, can anyone please show me where this factor of $2$ comes from? Or put another way, show that $$\fbox{$\epsilon_{ijk}\left(\hat a_j \hat b_k-\hat b_k \hat a_j\right)=2\epsilon_{ijk}\hat a_j\hat b_k$}\tag{a}$$

The proof does not have to be rigorous, it need only apply to a particular case, (like I tried to calculate above for the case of $j$ and $k$ running from $1$ to $2$).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Starting with: $\varepsilon_{ijk}a_jb_ k-\varepsilon_{ijk}a_kb_j $

We take the second term: $-\varepsilon_{ijk}a_kb_j=+\varepsilon_{ikj}a_kb_j$. This works because $ijk\to ikj$ is an odd permutation, so it generates a negative sign. We’re summing over $j$ and $k$, so provided we stay consistent we can rename them. Thus, the second term becomes $+\varepsilon_{ijk}a_jb_k$, which is identical to the first term, hence the factor of 2.

**EDIT**

Starting with: $\varepsilon_{ijk}[a_j,b_k]=\varepsilon_{ijk}a_jb_k-\varepsilon_{ijk}b_ka_j$ (Compare this to the expression above; they are different)

Then, manipulating this:

$$\varepsilon_{ijk}a_jb_k-\varepsilon_{ijk}b_ka_j=\varepsilon_{ijk}a_jb_k+\varepsilon_{ikj}b_ka_j=\varepsilon_{ijk}a_jb_k+\varepsilon_{ijk}b_ja_k$$

(Note how this is different from the math before the edit. The idea is the same, but the operators are never interchanged)

Continuing forward by adding "$0$":

$$\varepsilon_{ijk}(a_jb_k+b_ja_k+a_jb_k-a_jb_k)=2\varepsilon_{ijk}a_jb_k+\varepsilon_{ijk}(b_ja_k-a_jb_k)$$

$$=2\varepsilon_{ijk}a_jb_k-\varepsilon_{ikj}b_ja_k-\varepsilon_{ijk}a_jb_k=2\varepsilon_{ijk}a_jb_k-\varepsilon_{ijk}b_ka_j-\varepsilon_{ijk}a_jb_k=2\epsilon_{ijk}a_jb_k-\varepsilon_{ijk}\{a_j,b_k\}$$

Where $\{a_k,b_j\}$ denotes an anticommutator. But this means:

$$\varepsilon_{ijk}[a_j,b_k]=2\varepsilon_{ijk}a_jb_k-\varepsilon_{ijk}\{a_j,b_k\}$$

Thus, the property you give in your question is only possible if $\{a_j,b_k\}=0$.

Comment: Just moved a minus sign inside of math. It used to look like a hyphen. Hope you don't mind.

Comment: @moboDawn_φ Thanks for your answer, I'm slightly confused what the justification is for relabelling $j \to k$ and $k \to j$ *just* for the second term. You say "provided we stay consistent we can rename them". But doesn't being consistent mean that $\varepsilon_{ijk}a_jb_ k-\varepsilon_{ijk}a_kb_j=\varepsilon_{ijk}a_jb_ k+\varepsilon_{ikj}a_kb_j=\varepsilon_{ikj}a_kb_ j+\varepsilon_{ijk}a_jb_k$? In other words, I thought that relabelling the indices on one term meant that the same relabelling must be done for all terms.

Comment: Ah, so we must stay consistent in each term (as opposed to their sum). There is an implied sum over $j$ and $k$, and this sum happens in both terms. However, the summation in the first term doesn’t affect the summation in the second term, so we can relabel the indices in one term but not the other. Try writing out the summation signs, as it can make this explanation clearer.

Comment: @moboDawn_φ Okay, thanks for explaining. I just have just one more question for you if that's okay. Is the equality marked with the red question mark above it true? I'm just slightly confused since $j$ and $k$ are summed over it seems like I could equally write $\epsilon_{ijk}(\hat a_k \hat b_j-\hat b_j \hat a_k)$ for eqn. $(2)$, that's what your answer has taught me anyway.

Comment: @FutureCop:
The equality mark and the equation makes no sense. First of all you probably meant $\varepsilon^{ijk}(a_jb_k-a_kb_j)$ but you calculate $\varepsilon^{ijk}(a_jb_k-a_jb_k)$. Also, $\varepsilon^{ijk}$ and $\varepsilon_{ijk}$ are only defined for dimension $n=3$. More generally, the Levi-Civita symbol $\varepsilon^{h1\dots h_r}$ is only defined for $r=n$ (the dimension). So in any summation of over $j$ and $k$ you need to run them from 1 to 3 since your Levi-Civita has three indices.

Comment: @ContraKinta Thanks for the reply, however, please remember that the $\hat a$ and $\hat b$ are operators and hence cannot be assumed to commute. Why did you use the contravariant version of the Levi-Civita? Okay, so all I'm trying to do is write $\epsilon_{i12}((\hat a_1 \hat b_2-\hat a_2 \hat b_1)-(\hat b_2\hat a_1-\hat b_1 \hat a_2))$ in a compact form which I thought was equal to $\epsilon_{ijk}(\hat a_j \hat b_k-\hat b_k \hat a_j)$. If this is wrong then please tell me what is the correct expression.

Comment: Too long for comment, see answer

Comment: @FutureCop, in my answer I realized I assumed that they commuted. I think ContraKinta is in correct in acknowledging the existence of some sort of anticommutation relation. Without some sort of relation like this, we can't derive that factor of $2$.

Comment: @moboDawn_φ Sorry to resurrect this discussion but I fail to see how you assumed that $\hat a$ and $\hat b$ commuted in your answer above. I see no change in the ordering of $\hat a$ and $\hat b$ so what's the problem? In a similar way why should the $\hat a$ and $\hat b$ anticommute? You say that "without some sort of relation like this, we can't derive that factor of $2$". But you derived the factor of $2$ just fine in your answer. As I said before, sorry to bring this up, I'm just curious why you made these comments.

Comment: See the edit I added

Answer (score 3):

This didn't fit in the comment section:

Something is very wrong here. For the case $n=3$ and $i=1$ the only non-zero contribution to the contracted sum is

$$2\varepsilon_{1jk}\hat{a}_j \hat{b}_k=2(\varepsilon_{123}\hat{a}_2 \hat{b}_3+\varepsilon_{132}\hat{a}_3 \hat{b}_2)=2(\hat{a}_2 \hat{b}_3-\hat{a}_3 \hat{b}_2)$$

The same calculation for the  expression $\varepsilon_{ijk}(\hat{a}_j \hat{b}_k-\hat{b}_k \hat{a}_j)$ ($n=3$ and $i=1$)

$$\varepsilon_{1jk}(\hat{a}_j \hat{b}_k-\hat{b}_k \hat{a}_j)=\hat{a}_2\hat{b}_3 - \hat{a}_3\hat{b}_2 + \hat{b}_2\hat{a}_3 - \hat{b}_3\hat{a}_2$$

Clearly, those two are not the same unless somehow

$$
\hat{a}_2\hat{b}_3 - \hat{a}_3\hat{b}_2 = \hat{b}_2\hat{a}_3 - \hat{b}_3\hat{a}_2
$$

One way you can make this work is to randomly add the anti symmetric condition $\hat{a}_j\hat{b}_k=-\hat{b}_k\hat{a}_j$

Comment: (+1) Ah yes I realize I overlooked this in my answer. I wonder if perhaps there was some sort of “implicit” quantization that happened, in which case there would be some sort of commutator / anticommutator relation satisfied. Or something with the structure constants (I’ve seen this pop up in SU(2) gluon theory where pre-quantization indexing the fields makes them commute)

Comment: @ContraKinta Thanks for the answer and explanation, I think I understand what you mean now, I had to write my response as an answer also as it was too long for a comment. At the end of your answer you write, "randomly add the anti symmetric condition $\hat{a}_j\hat{b}_k=-\hat{b}_k\hat{a}_j$". But I never said that the $\hat a_j$ and $\hat b_k$ anticommute, so I don't see why you think you can use that condition.

Comment: @FutureCop they were saying that the only way for the property you listed in your OP to work is if that anticommutator is satisfied.

Comment: @moboDawn_φ But why does the anticommutator need to be satisfied? In your answer you showed that $\varepsilon_{ijk}(\hat a_j \hat b_k-\hat b_k \hat a_j)=2\epsilon_{ijk}\hat a_j\hat b_k$ *without* assuming that $[\hat a_j, \hat b_k]=0$ or $\{\hat a_j, \hat b_k\}=0$.

Comment: I realized in my answer I swapped the order of $a$ and $b$. So I used $a_jb_k-b_ja_k$. Which you can still use my technique to reorder the $j$ and $k$, but it won’t necessarily reorder the $a$ and $b$

Answer (score 2):

**Not an answer but too long for a comment:**

So the calculations I made in my question were nonsensical as I was trying to consider just the $i$th component only, but as mentioned by @ContraKinta $i,j,k$ run from $1$ to $3$ to give the $27$ ($6$ non-zero) components of the Levi-Civita.

What I was trying to do is to show that $$\varepsilon_{ijk}(\hat a_j \hat b_k-\hat b_k \hat a_j)=2\epsilon_{ijk}\hat a_j\hat b_k$$ by explicitly writing out each component:

$$\begin{align}\varepsilon_{ijk}\left(\hat{a}_j \hat{b}_k-\hat{b}_k \hat{a}_j\right)&=\varepsilon_{ijk}\hat{a}_j \hat{b}_k-\varepsilon_{ijk}\hat{b}_k \hat{a}_j\\&=\varepsilon_{123}\hat{a}_2\hat{b}_3 + \varepsilon_{132}\hat{a}_3\hat{b}_2 - \varepsilon_{123}\hat{b}_3\hat{a}_2 - \varepsilon_{132}\hat{b}_2\hat{a}_3 \\&+\varepsilon_{213}\hat{a}_1\hat{b}_3 + \varepsilon_{231}\hat{a}_3\hat{b}_1 - \varepsilon_{213}\hat{b}_3\hat{a}_1 -\varepsilon_{231}\hat{b}_1\hat{a}_3\\&+\varepsilon_{312}\hat{a}_1\hat{b}_2 + \varepsilon_{321}\hat{a}_2\hat{b}_1 - \varepsilon_{312}\hat{b}_2\hat{a}_1 - \varepsilon_{321}\hat{b}_1\hat{a}_2\\&=\varepsilon_{123}\hat{a}_2\hat{b}_3 - \varepsilon_{123}\hat{a}_3\hat{b}_2 - \varepsilon_{123}\hat{b}_3\hat{a}_2 + \varepsilon_{123}\hat{b}_2\hat{a}_3 \\&-\varepsilon_{123}\hat{a}_1\hat{b}_3 + \varepsilon_{123}\hat{a}_3\hat{b}_1 + \varepsilon_{123}\hat{b}_3\hat{a}_1 -\varepsilon_{123}\hat{b}_1\hat{a}_3\\&+\varepsilon_{123}\hat{a}_1\hat{b}_2 - \varepsilon_{123}\hat{a}_2\hat{b}_1 - \varepsilon_{123}\hat{b}_2\hat{a}_1 + \varepsilon_{123}\hat{b}_1\hat{a}_2\\&=\varepsilon_{123}\left(\hat a_2 \hat b_3 - \hat a_3\hat b_2\right)-\varepsilon_{123}\left(\hat b_2 \hat a_3 - \hat b_3\hat a_2\right)\\&+\varepsilon_{123}\left(\hat a_3 \hat b_1 - \hat a_1\hat b_3\right)-\varepsilon_{123}\left(\hat b_1 \hat a_3 - \hat b_3\hat a_1\right)\\&+\varepsilon_{123}\left(\hat a_1 \hat b_2 - \hat a_2\hat b_1\right)-\varepsilon_{123}\left(\hat b_2 \hat a_1 - \hat b_1\hat a_2\right)\end{align}$$ where after the third equality I have written all $12$ terms using only $\varepsilon_{123}$ in order to try to spot a pattern and write it in a compact way. But I don't see a way of doing this via this method to prove the statement in the title, so it seems the only way to show that $$\varepsilon_{ijk}(\hat a_j \hat b_k-\hat b_k \hat a_j)=2\epsilon_{ijk}\hat a_j\hat b_k$$ is to do it in an abstract way (without specifying the values the indices take) as is done in the answer by @moboDawn_φ .